# While Loops Only Iterates Correctly Once

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I am working on a python script to brute force deobfuscate malicious Java Script I have been finding in security events. Long story short at one point in the process they are obfuscating the script that redirects to the payload with an XOR. So here is how I am going about this.
Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import subprocess
perl = "perl -pe 's/([;\}\{])/$"
userInput = input("")
tail = (r"\n/g'")
def deobBrute():
        count = 0
        while (count < 101):
                return(str(userInput)+str(perl)+str(count)+str(tail))
                count = count + 1
output = subprocess.Popen(deobBrute(), shell=True).wait
results = 0
while (results < 101):
        print(output)
        results = results + 1
```

The user input I am feeding it:

```
cat elsePageXoffset |
```

elsePageXoffest is the text file I am storing the obfuscate JS in.

It only iterates once however which unless they are obfuscating with XOR^1 does me no good.

Error message for all other iterations:

```
<bound method Popen.wait of <subprocess.Popen object at 0x7fb65c6c9128>>
```

Comment: You forgot to call `wait`.

Comment: `return` will exit the loop and the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your method (your tabbing is messed up), then the function will return `(str(userInput)+str(perl)+str(count)+str(tail))` straight away, and the rest of the function will not execute, consider using yield if you want to continue within the method and return more values. As yield returns a generator, you will need to iterate over the `deobBrute` in order to access the values

```
def deobBrute():
    count = 0
    while (count < 101):
        return(str(userInput)+str(perl)+str(count)+str(tail))
        count = count + 1

def deobBrute():
    count = 0
    while (count < 101):
        yield(str(userInput)+str(perl)+str(count)+str(tail))
        count = count + 1
```

Try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import subprocess
perl = "perl -pe 's/([;\}\{])/$"
userInput = input("")
tail = (r"\n/g'")

def deobBrute():
    for i in range(1, 102):
        yield "{0}{1}{2}{3}".format(userInput, perl, i, tail)

brute = deobBrute()

for i in brute:
    print(subprocess.Popen(i, shell=True))
```

Comment: that gives me AttirubteError 'Generator' obejct has not attirbute 'next'

Comment: Well the Python script is working but the overall goal is not. That variable perl is part of a perl script I am using. what I am trying to do is more of less have python run that perl script or                                                                        cat textFileName | perl -pe 's/([;\}]{])/$Python Script Number Change\n/g'

Comment: its not running it as a command in terminal, the file I am feeding into the python script is just getting printed 100 times without running the perl script on that text file, in the terminal.

Comment: I am not a smart man. I apologize its my perl script that needed to be fixed, this solution worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you return inside of the while loop, which means it is only going to run once

if you move the return outside of the while loop, your code should function

```
def deobBrute():
    count = 0
    while (count < 101):
        count = count + 1
    return(str(userInput)+str(perl)+str(count)+str(tail))
```